# Changing the current date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I am working with the date in my iPhone development. I need to increase the date by 24 hours from the current date.

Comment: 24 hours or one day? Don't want to see another alarm clock that wakes me up at the wrong time two times a year ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dateByAddingTimeInterval

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *datePlusOneDay = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24)]; //one day
```

Comment: Shouldn't it say `NSDate *datePlusOneDay`?

Comment: @NickWeaver you are right.. But it is already edited by Matthias.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
NSDate *tomorrow = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
```

Comment: addTimeInterval is a deprecated method in iOS4

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I went ahead an edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an NSTimeInterval. Since this is a double in seconds just add 24*60*60:

```
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSDate *twentyFourHoursLater = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24];
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the download date in the NSUserdefaults then check if 24 hours have passed?
If not notify the user that he/she will have to wait.

Comment: NSUserdefaults is not a keyword, I did not get you

Answer (score 0):

save the last download date in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And when you try to download just check for that date.

something like this:

```
- (BOOL)downloadDataForecedUpdate:(BOOL)forced {
    NSDate *lastDownloadDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDownloadDate"];
    if (forced || !lastDownloadDate || [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDownloadDate] > 24 * 60 * 60) {
        // start download
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myDownloadRequest delegate:self];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // process data

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastDownloadDate"];
}
```

you can call `[self downloadDataForecedUpdate:NO]` whereever it is appropriate. on application launch or in an IBAction. Use the return value of the method to either show a download indicator or a alert that tells the user he has to wait more.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are really trying to achieve, just adding 86,400 (or 60 * 60 * 24 ) to your time interval might not be what you want. If for example, the user experiences a daylight-savings adjustment, then you will be off by an hour, or even a day if it happens near midnight. A better method is to ask the NSCalendar for the result, which takes into account the users local time zone.

```
NSDate *start = yourDate;
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [NSDateComponents new];
[oneDay setDay:1];

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *end = [cal dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:start options:0];
```